# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

Tags: php, html, laravel

THIS IS MY VIEW CODE

```
<form method="POST" action="/update">
    Task Name:<input type="text" value="{{$task->TaskName}}" name="taskname"><br>
    Description:<input type="text" value="{{$task->Description}}" name="description"><br>
    Location id:<input type="text" value="{{$task->Location_id}}" name="location_id"><br>
    @if($task->status === 1)
    Status:<input type="checkbox" checked name="status"><br>
    @else
    Status:<input type="checkbox" name="status"><br>
    @endif
    Created at:<input type="" value="{{$task->created_at}}" name="created_at"><br>
    Modified at:<input type="date" value="{{$task->updated_at}}" name="modified_at"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="update" name="upadte" ><br>
    {{csrf_field()}}
</form>
```

THIS IS MY ROUTE CODE:

```
Route::get('/update', 'TasksController@update');
```

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER CODE FOR UPDATE:

```
public function update()
{
    dd("yoo");
    //return view('/update');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form method is `POST` and your route is `get`.

Change your route to `Route::post('update', 'TasksController@update');`

For form method `Get` you have to use `Route::get` and for `post` you have to use `Route::post`.

Beside that you can assign a name to the route,

`Route::post('update', 'TasksController@update')->name('TaskUpdate');`.

Then in your form method use `route()`, Like `method="{{route('TaskUpdate')}}"`, but your file extension should be `.blade.php`.